# why would kernel will schedule irq handler with another thread?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel

i come across a problem when i use a irq handler in linux;

i register a handler with a request_irq;

it can be called when the external hardware send a interrupt;

in the irq handler,the code is programmed as follows;

```
irqreturn_t irq_test_handler(int irq, void *desc)
{
wake_up_process(a_thread_handle);
mdelay(10);
printk("end the handler\n");
return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

a_thread_handle come from function : kthread_create(a_kthread....);

```
in a_kthread()
{
printk("in a kthread !\n");
}
```

so in my opinion , when irq happens;

it will print like this;

"

> end the handler
>
> in a kthread !

"

but in fact ;

it will print like this:

"

> in a kthread !
>
> end the handler

"

Can  some one explain this to me ?

Comment: Given that you _wake up a process_ and then _wait_ (in an IRQ handler! bad!), why do you expect the order to be "handler, process" instead of "process, handler"? Also, please use proper casing (upper-/lowercase); this reads awful.

Comment: Because we meet a very very low rate problem  the wake up thread run first than the irq handler, we just test if the problem will happen with this way . of course this just for a test ,because it's so stupid way to do this; ^^!   irq handler must run first than process right?

Comment: The IRQ handler _does_ run first; it just doesn't _finish_ first.

Comment: It is normal that IRQ handler is executed on one CPU, but thread `a_kthread` on another. So handler doesn't prevent execution of the thread.

Comment: you mean ,it will be scheduled by the kernel when it was in irq handler?  can you show me the code for me ?

Comment: @ Tsyvarev  but the log shows they are on the same cpu ;

Comment: If they are on same core, maybe your system supports interrupt nesting  . That is to say a higher priority irq (maybe timer) interrupts your irq handler.

Comment: yearp,but after timer irq ,then it will back to irq handler,then to thread.the thread won't to run first in the same cpu.@Chris Tsui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do by `wake_up_process()` is what `request_threaded_irq()` is providing. Calling `request_irq()` is the same as `request_threaded_irq()` but with `thread_fn=NULL`. If you provide your thread and return `IRQ_WAKE_THREAD`, your thread will be waked after your handler function completed. I think that was your original intention (see [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/genericirq/API-request-threaded-irq.html)).

To try if this is a multi core effect set your system to be single core

```
#!/usr/bin/sudo bash
CPU_DIR="/sys/devices/system/cpu"
NEXT=$(( 1 - $( cat ${CPU_DIR}/cpu1/online ) ))
for d in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*
do
  CPU=${d##*/}
  if [ ${CPU} == "cpuidle" ]; then continue; fi
  if [ ${CPU} == "cpu0" ]; then continue; fi
  echo -n $CPU $( cat $d/online )
  echo "${NEXT}" >$d/online
  echo " => " $( cat $d/online )
done
```

and try again. First call is going single core, second call back. You can also reboot using kernel parameter `nosmp` or `maxcpus=0` to disable SMP activation entirely (see [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/smp.c)).

*Just for documentation (see comments below):* **It turned out to be a multi core effect with the thread running on a different core and thus starting immediately.**

Comment: thanks for your answer. the mdelay function in kernel just let the cpu wait ,not like the sleep function. and i put it in a irq handler top part, in my opinion ,i won't chedule with another thread until it finish its irq handler.  can your show some code to show this schedule?

Comment: what does the SA_INTERRUPT mean?  i use the code to request a irq:    ret=request_irq(g_irq,irq_test_handler ,4 , "myirq", NULL);

Comment: "interrupt handling has been done with top half (i.e. the "hard" irq) that actually responds to the hardware interrupt and a bottom half (or "soft" irq) that is scheduled by the top half to do additional processing. The top half executes with interrupts disabled, so it is imperative that it do as little as possible to keep the system responsive. "     i put the code in top half,so this part should be not schdule .  i don't know if my opinion it's right or not.

Comment: Top half is the handler `handler` and bottom half the kernel thread `thread_fn` which is `NULL` if you use `request_irq()`. So do not use `wake_up_process()` but rather `request_threaded_irq()`. That is the intended way.

Comment: thanks , now my question is why it will be scheduled .of course ,there is many way to reach my aim.but from the design of kernel's irq ,i want to know why this will happen.

Comment: What kernel version are you using?

Comment: 1 VERSION = 3              
   2 PATCHLEVEL = 10          
   3 SUBLEVEL = 72            
   4 EXTRAVERSION =           
   5 NAME = TOSSUG Baby Fish

Comment: kernel version : 3.10

Comment: Try to use `trace_printk()` instead of `printk()` and look at `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace` (see [here](http://lwn.net/Articles/365835/)). Is it still in the wrong order?

Comment: OK,i ll test this,wait for some minutes.

Comment: I guess that Tsyvarev is right. Your thread is running on a different core while your IRQ handler is busy waiting. That is why you should use `request_threaded_irq()` for correct orders.

Comment: i check the log,it was output the in the same cpu.

Comment: add "trace_printk" ,it's the same problem.

Comment: Ok, next try the script (in answer) and set your fine i7 to be single core (even without extra virtual cores).

Comment: dear kellerspeicher ,maybe it's hard for me to do this ,i am debugging a problem in a phone.!~~~~ haha  and the trace log it seems not output ; bad luck~ or i can see what happened.

Comment: But even embedded you can boot with `maxcpus=1`.

Comment: it's pity that the phone can't boot up at all. reset all the time when in kernel.

Comment: should use cmdline maxcpus=0 not 1 ; ^^!

Comment: 528  * Command-line option of "nosmp" or "maxcpus=0" will disable SMP
529  * activation entirely (the MPS table probe still happens, though).

Comment: Right. I corrected the answer. What phone are you using Saifish, Meego, Meamo or a rooted Android? Or are your currently writing a new one supporting 34 languages :-)

Comment: i just check a bug coming from the tester;

Comment: normally we don't use a single core to do this. now the qcom arch cpu owned 8 cpus  .  i don't boot phone with single core before,maybe there is some other problems when single core boot.

Comment: Hi,Kellerspeicher. can i make the thread on the some cpu to run ? i found that the thread will be run in a different cpu . eg: the irq handler run on cpu 0 ,and the thread will run on cpu 1  or 4;

Comment: Hi,Kellerspeicher, the problem indeed comes from that irq handler run on one cpu ,the thread run on another cpu.  USE the smp_processor_id() can get the cpu on which the thread or irq run.  USE the thread_bind() ,we can choose  which cpu the thread will run on after kthread_create(); thanks for your help;